# Complex MySQL Query, filter from multi table

Tags: mysql

I have a ORDER_TABLE to store all ORDER ( order_id , order_name )

A ORDER_ITEMS_TABLE store all items of each order ( order_item_id , order_id , item_name ). Each row is a item and a order have many row in ORDER_ITEMS_TABLE

I have a input that allow user to enter a list of items, separate by comma (item1,item2,item3)
and when user submit, i should get all orders from ORDER_TABLE that contain all items above (item1 AND item2 AND item3)

Help me please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you parse the user's list of comma-separated items before you add it to the query, otherwise you'll leave yourself open to SQL injection attacks.

```
SELECT ot.order_name, oit.item_name
FROM ORDER_ITEMS_TABLE oit
INNER JOIN ORDER_TABLE ot ON ot.order_id = oit.order_id
WHERE oit.order_item_id IN (your,list,of,items)
```

Comment: thank for the help but i need to select orders that contain all-of-them, not any-of-them

Comment: That's quite a bit different than the original question.  You could use the query I gave you and pare down the results on the scripting side - I can't think of an elegant SQL-only solution off the top of my head for the new question.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Crontabs answer:

```
$items = $_POST['items'];
$item_array = explode(',',$items);
foreach ($item_array as $item) 
{
  $item = mysql_real_escape_string($item);
}
$items = implode("','", $item_array);
$query = "SELECT ot.order_name, oit.item_name     
          FROM ORDER_ITEMS_TABLE oit     
          INNER JOIN ORDER_TABLE ot ON ot.order_id = oit.order_id     
          WHERE oit.order_item_id IN ('$items')  ";
```

Now you've properly escaped those CSV items.

Comment: user904427 didn't tag it "php" so I didn't make any assumptions.  ;)

Comment: @Crontab, according to user's profile he's a php-user so it made sense :-)